# Switch statements and double values

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am just learning how to use switch statements. I am trying to create a shopping cart of items sold at a grocery store. I have to create a program that adds the values of the items sold and then print the final value. This is what I have so far but when I terminate my program I get an error and it doesn't display the final value.

Any help is much appreciated!!

```
package Exercises;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalculatingSales {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int total = 0;
        int prod1Count = 0, prod2Count = 0, prod3Count = 0, prod4Count = 0, prod5Count = 0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.printf("%s%n%s%n    %s%n    %s%n    %s%n","Enter product number sold: "  //prompt user to enter input
                ,"NOTE: Product number must be between 1 & 5",
                "To terminate input... ",
                "On UNIX/Linus?mac OS X type <Ctrl> d then press Enter",
                "On Windows type <Ctrl> z then press Enter");

        while(input.hasNext())
        {
            int item = input.nextInt();
            total =+ item;

            double product1;
            double product2;
            double product3;
            double product4;
            double product5;

            switch (item + total)
            {
                case 1:
                    product1 = 2.98;
                    ++prod1Count;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    product2 = 4.50;
                    ++prod2Count;
                    break;

                case 3:
                    product3 = 9.98;
                    ++prod3Count;
                    break;

                case 4:
                    product4 = 4.49;
                    ++prod4Count;
                    break;

                case 5:
                    product5 = 6.87;
                    ++prod5Count;
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("ERROR. You did not enter a value between 1 & 5!");
                    break;

            }//end switch   

        }//end while

        double shoppingCart = (double) total;

        System.out.printf("%nTotal retail value of all products is: $%d", shoppingCart);
    }   
}
```

Comment: It should be `total += item;`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
System.out.printf("%nTotal retail value of all products is: $%d", shoppingCart);
```

The `printf` is expecting an `int` but you are passing an `double` as an argument.

Try this:

```
System.out.printf("%nTotal retail value of all products is: $%.2f", shoppingCart);
```

Also you should change `total =+ item;` to `total += item;`

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with the code. The error at the end is because you are trying to output a double and specifying an integer to print. `$%d` should be `$%f` however to make money display to two decimal places you can use `$%.2f`. More information on formatting can be found in this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

The major problems though are in your loop. The switch statement should only be passed the item number you want to compare to and do something accordingly.So the switch simply has to be `switch (item)` . There is a simpler way to do the total and do the switch. You can keep a running `total` by adding to it the value of the product the person selected each time through the loop. Upon exiting it should be the total amount for all the items selected. If you enter an item out of range it effectively adds 0.

At the end you really should close the scanner to do proper cleanup so `input.close()` would be a good idea as well.

The code could look something like:

```
package Exercises;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalculatingSales {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        double total = 0.0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.printf("%s%n%s%n    %s%n    %s%n    %s%n","Enter product number sold: "  //prompt user to enter input
                ,"NOTE: Product number must be between 1 & 5",
                "To terminate input... ",
                "On UNIX/Linus?mac OS X type <Ctrl> d then press Enter",
                "On Windows type <Ctrl> z then press Enter");

        while(input.hasNext())
        {
            double prodvalue = 0.0;

            int item = input.nextInt();

            switch (item)
            {
                case 1:
                    prodvalue = 2.98;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    prodvalue = 4.50;
                    break;

                case 3:
                    prodvalue = 9.98;
                    break;

                case 4:
                    prodvalue = 4.49;
                    break;

                case 5:
                    prodvalue = 6.87;
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("ERROR. You did not enter a value between 1 & 5!");
                    break;

            }//end switch   

            total += prodvalue;

        }//end while

        double shoppingCart = total;

        System.out.printf("%nTotal retail value of all products is: $%.2f", shoppingCart);
        input.close();
    } 
}
```

There are much better ways of doing this but as time goes on you will probably learn how this program could be simplified. I wanted to keep the code somewhat structured the way you seemed to be handling things.

If you need the counts of each individual item then you will have to modify the code above to add them back in. I realize this solution may have oversimplified what you needed but at a basic level it keeps the overall total right.